# Multiple twitter feeds in embedded timeline no longer working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I have been combining two Twitter accounts into one embedded timeline using the methods described here... [Multiple twitter feeds in embedded timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114824/multiple-twitter-feeds-in-embedded-timeline)

around September however, it just stopped working . I read some things about Twitter changing their APIs.. https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecating-widget-settings/102295 but not sure if it is actually this. Does anyone know of any new alternative ways t do this? This is the code I have been using..[image: broken feed]

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="800" href="https://twitter.com   /search?q=from%3Ayoursaypays%20OR%20from%3ATLFResearch" data-widget-id="917683742759636992">Tweets about from:yoursaypays OR from:TLFResearch</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's that obvious from searching, but the answer was rather staring me in the face. Within a Twitter account, simply constructing [a list](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-lists) and using that in an embedded timeline works as well as the aforementioned method which seems deprecated.